# InvalidQuery key [...] with EclipseLink CriteriaQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

Migrating from Hibernate 4.2.6 to EclipseLink 2.4.2 (or 2.5.1), many criteria queries that used to be fine now abruptly break up with EclipseLink saying:

For instance:

```
Exception Description: Invalid query key [
Query Key posts Base com.comax.model.mailing.Post] 
in expression.Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=Post )
```

where `Point` entity has a unidirectional 1-N relationship to `Post`.

The query is

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Post> q = cb.createQuery(Post.class);
Root<Point> root = q.from(Point.class);
Join<Point, Post> p1 = root.join("posts", JoinType.INNER);
Path<String> city = p1.get("city"); 

q.select(p1).distinct(true).where(cb.like(city, "L%"));

TypedQuery<Post> tq = em.createQuery(q);
List<Post> results = tq.getResultList();
```

The error message leaves me quite perplex. These `Post` and `Point` entities both inherit (JOINED strategy) from a common `Base` entity that is mentioned in `Query Key posts Base ...`

However, the JPQL equivalent

```
results = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT DISTINCT post FROM Point p JOIN p.posts post WHERE post.city LIKE 'L%' ORDER BY post.city", 
    Post.class).getResultList();
```

runs as expected.

How do I achieve this? Or am I missing something? Is there something specific to EclipseLink when it comes to criteria queries?

Comment: Try using the point class when creating the query.

Comment: Do you mean `CriteriaQuery<Point> q = cb.createQuery(Point.class)`? I'm selecting `Post` entities here. Could you please provide a brief code snippet? Many thanks!